# Producing a pip-installable module without using distutils or setuptools

Tags: python, pip

In the Python documentation (https://docs.python.org/2.7/distutils/setupscript.html) it is described a way for making a module installable via "pip install". Suppose that, for unknown reasons, you cannot rely on distutils or setuptools (a potential situation is described in my other question [Distutils appharently fails with a (working) SWIG extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48829372/distutils-appharently-fails-with-a-working-swig-extension)).

Is there an alternative way for obtaining a pip-installable package?

Ps: my module is written via SWIG (C wrapping). It works when compiled as usual, but it seems not to work if I compile it by using distutils/setuptools. This is the key point of the related linked question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible but it's possible in the same way as it's possible to rewrite an OS in assembler — it's possible but quite hard.

If you have to avoid `setuptools` try creating an installer using other tools. Look at [conda](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tutorials/build-pkgs.html), [PyInstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/), [cx_Freeze](https://anthony-tuininga.github.io/cx_Freeze/).